# How can I create own gradle dependency in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio-2.2

For developing android applications by using Android Studio, generally we add dependencies in `build.gradle` instead of adding jars or libraries.

Example given below

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
```

Comment: I did some Googling first and [this](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-upload-library-to-jcenter-maven-central-as-dependency/en) appears first.

Comment: Yeah It is ok,i also looked into this, but this is not more helpful.do you implemented it in before.

Comment: I have done it couple of times so yes.

Answer (score 0):

> How can i create own gradle dependency in android studio?

You have to publish your library on [JCenter](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter). You can find steps of publishing it on Google.